# How to force MPICH to use GCC (g++) instead of PGI(pg++)?

Tags: linker, mpi, wrapper, mpich, mpic++

I am compiling an MPI + OpenMP written using C++, and I need to test it on a system using the g++ compiler, but currently that system is using PGI compilers under the mpic++ wrapper.

Is there any way to force it, to use g++ instead of pgc++  ?

Comment: Did you try reading the [manual](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www1/mpicxx.html)?

Comment: I didn't know about mpicxx -cxx=[compiler name]

Comment: You can also set the compiler at runtime using the `MPICH_CXX` environment variable.